# JQuery Ajax Issues when trying to replace a div (using MVC 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having issues with getting jquery ajax to work properly with my button and replace a div. Below is my code and here is a link to my github repo, if anyone could help point me in the right direction, that would be great. [Repo](https://github.com/mslawson/studentInfo)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document'.ready(function() {
        $('#ajbutton').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/GetStudentInfo",
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
            }).success(function(result) {
                $('#replace').hide();
                $('#studentDetails').show();
                $('#studentDetails').html(result);
            })
        });
    }));
</script>
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: Check console for errors .

Comment: `"document"` should just be `document` (ie not a string) and you're missing a `)` before `.ready`

Comment: `$('document'.ready(function() {` change to  `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Check the network logs in the browser debugger to see what type of response you're getting. My guess is that GetStudentInfo is not setup to allow get.  Since its MVC you might need to decorate your action method with allowGet

Comment: Thanks Tushar.  The correction shows that the GET request is working.  Now I just need to get the right content pushed over.

Comment: Is the url section supposed to specify the Controller/Action?

Comment: @MatthewDavid pass `data:{name:'value'}` like this  .

Comment: @TusharGupta is that in place of "dataType: 'html' ?

Comment: @MatthewDavid No . If you want to variables to pass GET variables use `data:{name:'value'}` inside `$.ajax`

Comment: @TusharGupta  My calls work great if im on my localhost/home , however, if I don't have the home controller active the GET fails with a 404.  How can I rememdy this?

Comment: @MatthewDavid Read [404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). I think your page is not found. URL not found .

Comment: @TusharGupta I know it's not found, but that only occurs when I run the  script from localhost/  if I run it from localhost/home/  (which both display the same page) it works fine.  So is there a way to add the control somewhere in the ajax or is it a routing issue?  Anyway to force the localhost/  to go to localhost/home/ ?

Comment: @MatthewDavid I can't help you with that make it a new question .Should i post the answer which helped you till now ?

Comment: @TusharGupta I did ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124778/url-param-in-ajax